# How to use @MockBean without having to @Inject the Bean again?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, micronaut, mockk

Is there a more concise / elegant way to reach this functionality in Micronaut?

```
@MicronautTest
class ControllerTest {
    @Inject
    @field:Client("/")
    lateinit var client: RxHttpClient

    @Inject
    lateinit var redeemService: RedeemService

    @MockBean(RedeemService::class)
    fun redeemService(): RedeemService = mockk {
        every { validate(any()) } returns true
    }

    @Test
    fun test() {
        // some logic triggering a call to redeemService
        verify(exactly = 1) {
            redeemService.validate("123")
        }
    }
}
```

To me it looks like redundant work to have to declare the `@MockBean` and then also having to `@Inject` the previously declared `@MockBean`.
From what I remember, in Spring Boot this is just an annotation on a `lateinit var`.

Did I misunderstand or overlook something?

Comment: "To me it looks like redundant work to have to declare the MockBean and then also having to Inject the previously declared MockBean" - Usually the mock isn't inject into the test, it is injected into components being tested.  In your case your test doesn't test anything other than the mock itself so it isn't clear what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: I guess the Mock can serve 2 purposes: isolate the behavior of the Unit from the rest of the system + capture what information has crossed this boundary (and how often etc.). To me it´s perfectly normal to regularly use both of these features, that´s why I´m searching for something similar to https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/springmockk also in Micronaut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the mock bean, for replacing the service and inject it everywhere in your application .. if you want to do some verification you eighter have to inject it back or create instance within your class and return that with the mock bean

```
private val redeemService: RedeemService = mockk {
    every { validate(any()) } returns true
}

@MockBean(RedeemService::class)
fun redeemService() = redeemService
```

Comment: I guess it´s a valid solution. I´ll just wait a few more days if other answers arrive, otherwise I´ll accept this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, `MockBean` are NO-OP collaborators that are intended to be DI-ed into dependent beans instead of relying on concrete bean implementations.

If within a test fixture ~ your tested feature scope ~ you have to verify collaborator calls or provide custom response to other collaborators calls, then you have to inject it.

This may seem, as stated, like redundancy but it's not and it SHOULD be done in such a way otherwise Micronaut (or any other framework doing so) would have a little design flaw.

Relying on custom implementations (annotations in this case) to act as bean providers and injection points within tests would result in non-deterministic behavior and internal tight-coupling to framework specificities as you will be injecting your dependencies in your test fixture differently from the way you'll be doing it in your actual application code, and that should be avoided.

In short, if your bean (mock or concrete) make it to the your test implementation through the `@Inject` annotation, then you are assured it will work the same when injected into real application code since a test fixture is a bean itself.

Comment: So would you say this is a design flaw? https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/springmockk

Comment: In my humble point of vue, yes. And Micronaut helps you avoid it.